# Converting Delphi TPoint to C# Point

Tags: delphi, c#-4.0, graphics, vcl, delphi-6

I am trying to convert some Delphi code as we are re-writing a Delphi 6.0 (VCL) application in .Net. I am not sure and could not figure out the comparison between 2 Delphi Tpoints(x,y) with that of C# Point(x,y).

I am trying to draw a line between 2 points but since I have no idea how Delphi draws it, I am not able to set the C# coordinates for it.

The Delphi code is simple:

```
Canvas.MoveTo(x, y - 128);    
Canvas.LineTo(x, y);
```

I know about the C# coordinates though about 72 Points per inch and need to calculate the pixel density. But I am not sure about the Delphi PPI.

Any would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: If someone is wondering what **TPoint** I am talking when there is none in my code snippet, Canvas.MoveTo sets the PenPos property of the canvas which is of type **TPoint**.

Comment: Reasons for down votes would be appreciated. Please just don't down vote cause you didn't like the question. Or didn't understand it.

Comment: +1; this is a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the exact question is that's being asked here. You have no Delphi `TPoint` in your code snippet; you simply have client rect logical coordinates.

The origin is at `X = 0, Y = 0`, which is the top left corner of the client area. Increasing `X` moves the position to the right, and increasing `Y` moves the position down. Logical units are pixels, so starting at the origin of `0, 0`, a `Canvas.MoveTo(10, 10)` would set the new drawing position in from the left edge 10 pixels and down from the top 10 pixels, and a `Canvas.LineTo(20, 20)` from there would draw a line from the point at `10, 10` to `20, 20`.

`TCanvas.MoveTo` and `TCanvas.LineTo` are simply wrappers around the underlying Windows GDI functions [`MoveToEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with an always `NULL` third parameter) and [`LineTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As far as the C# equivalent, if you're referring to `System.Drawing.Point`, the units used are exactly the same (although I'm not sure where the origin is based by default). Given an origin of `0, 0`, `System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)` should be the same position described above - 10 pixels from the left edge and 10 pixels down from the top edge.

A quick check confirms that the origin in a WinForms application is in fact the top left corner of the client area, using:

```
// Delphi code
procedure TForm3.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clRed;
  Canvas.MoveTo(0, 0);
  Canvas.LineTo(100, 100);
end;

// C# code
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen newPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(newPen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 100));
}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Side by side output comparison]

Comment: As far as I knew, the Graphics method in C# are dependent on the Pixel density of the screen or the client area and would differ from device to device. What I know is that the device would be distributed to Points where in the density is 72 points per inches. Though, right now I am going with the explanation you have provided. Please update in case if you come across any other information in this regard. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Also, just to explain about TPoint, TCanvas.MoveTo, sets the PenPos property of the canvas which is a TPoint.

Comment: You can set e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel to have it operate on pixel, regardless of DPI or PPI.